# Difference between tortoise svn and cvs?

Tags: networking

In my office we are using TortoiseSVN and it is not properly installed so I saw TortoiseCVS.  My question is: are they the same or do they work differently and which one is better to use?

Answer (score 2):

CVS is based on RCS files of versions control while SVN is a relational database (BerkleyDB). 
CVS supports rollback commit feature while SVN not, you need to commit a second time and overwrite your previous commit (manual rollback). CVS only tracks modification file by file while SVN tracks a whole commit as a new revision, which means that it is easier to follow the history of your project.

Usefull links:

- [Comparison of CVS and Subversion](http://www.softeng.rl.ac.uk/media/uploads/publications/2010/03/cvs-svn.pdf)
- [Conparing svn and cvs](http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2010/08/25/comparin-svn-and-cvs/)

Comment: Not that it matters, but Subversion switch to SQLite for its internal database a while back.

Answer (score 1):

Those are just graphic clients for the same service. Try and choose your favorite.

Answer (score 1):

these software are used by software programmer. one is command prompt and the other is easily used by user